# Laravel how to get only relation data

Tags: laravel, relationship

this is my User.php relation code

```
    public function activities()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Activities::class, 'builder');
    }
```

and this is my query to get only relation data

```
return User::whereHas('activities', fn($query) => $query->where('user_id', 1))
            ->paginate();
```

but it returns only user data without appling any relation, and its pagination not get to use `pluck`

i have also tried this

```
User::where('username', request()->username)->has('activities')->paginate();
```

but i need only get relation data not user with relation, and i prefer do it with `whereHas`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create reverse relation for `Activities` model:

```php
class Activities extends Model
{
    // ...
    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

And get all the activities using Activities builder:

```php
$paginated = Acitivities::query()
    ->whereHas('user', static function(Builder $userQuery) {
        $userQuery->where('name', request()->username); // Think about security!
    })
    ->paginate();
```

Note: All the models must be named in singular (e.g. Activity, User, Product and etc.).

Comment: Thank you it works very well, by the way whats the problem with security? you mean other ppl can access to other users activities?

Comment: @Jackson yes, but it depends on business-logic, maybe some User cannot access other Users activities.